# Android Background Service request php and send notification

Tags: php, android, download, background-service

I'm a little bit confused why I'm not able to find a result for my question.

I want to create a Background Service that requests a php file returns a json string and then sends a Notification with content from this json string.

So I am able to send like notifications to my users.

How is this possible.

Windows Phone back then had like a periodic Background service running all 30 Minutes and when I want to send instant Notifications I had to use there Service.

Comment: Android and google provide all the goodies to do just that. Go ahead, google it !  As it is this is too broad for this format. Reopen a question later if you get stuck on a specific programming question/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [`Volley`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKgObxrevVAhUBP5oKHVUXC80QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fvolley%2Findex.html&usg=AFQjCNFwn_mUDzUwjOceF4Lxu3Q4Zmsd_w).

You can use this code as a reference :

```
package com.exampfle.real; 

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class RealService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG="RealService";
    private boolean isRunning=false;
    private IBinder mBinder=new MyBinder();
    private boolean intenetAccess=false;
/* Change here */ 
    private RequestQueue reQueue;
    private final String url="http://www.google.com";

    public boolean SendRequest() 
    {
/* Change here */
    reQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); 
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,
                url, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override 
            public void onResponse( 
                    String response) {

                intenetAccess=true;
            } 
        }, 

        new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onErrorResponse( 
                    VolleyError error) {

                intenetAccess=false;

            } 
        }); 

        try{ 
            reQueue.add(request);
        } 
        catch(Exception e){}

        return intenetAccess;

    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate(); 
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");

        isRunning=true;

    } 



    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return mBinder;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onRebind");
        super.onRebind(intent);
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onUnBind");
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 

    isRunning=false;

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy(); 
    } 



    public class MyBinder extends Binder
    { 
        RealService getService() 
        { 
            return RealService.this;
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Hope it helped you :)**